# Calculate Potential Gravity Energy converted when star collapses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

We want to calculate how much gravitational potential energy converts to heat, when the star has no nuclear fusion, the gravity will cause the star to  shrink in nano seconds.

Now assuming the Sun shrinks to 10km radius (an event we know is not possible), calculate the gravity potential energy that this will release.

I simply assume to 0km radius, for any point on Sun, it has gravity potential energy as

$$
U = mgh = m_i g r_i = \rho_{density} dV r_{distance\;to\;core}
$$

So the total energy as below, I'm using triple integral

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta{U} &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^r g \;\rho_{sun}\; \rho^3 \sin\theta\;  dr\; d\phi \;d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}  g \frac{1}{4}r^4 \rho_{sun} \sin\theta\;d\theta \; d\phi \;  \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} - g \frac{1}{4}r^4 \rho_{sun} \cos\theta \;|_0^{\pi}d\phi \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} 2 g \frac{1}{4}r^4 \rho_{sun} d\phi \\
&= 2\pi 2 g \frac{1}{4}r^4 \rho_{sun} \\
&= r^4 \pi g  \rho_{sun}
\end{align}
$$

I'm not sure if my way is wrong or not, because as the teacher's the result is

$$
10^{46} J
$$

while my result is

$$
10^{40}J
$$

The result is calculated in some lines of code in the Ruby language

`r=7e8 #sun radius in meter
rho = 1411 #density kg/m^3
g = 10
u= r**4 * Math::PI * g * rho
p u`

It would print "1.0643122149350688e+40"

Comment: Hint: U=mgh is an approximation.

Comment: Your formula for potential energy is wrong. Recall that the general formula for potential energy due to interaction between two bodies of mass $M$ and $m$ is $U=-\frac{GMm}{r}$ where $r$ is the distance between them.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on gravitational potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy)

Comment: yes, what they're all saying is: why are you using $g=10$ when that's the gravitational acceleration on the surface of Earth?